# Ideas for custom, zoomable floorplan with interactive markers?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking to implement a widget that shows a floorplan with a custom image. It needs to have markers that show specific points on the plan, and the markers should pan and zoom with the floorplan so they remain in the same position relative to the plan. Imagine a normal map with markers, but I want to show a floorplan image instead of map data.

I've seen this video which uses a GridView:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZMqaHSs6CM however I don't think it's the best solution for my scenario, as my floorplan images may have different numbers of markers that won't fit in to the grid resolution/dimensions.

Any ideas which widgets/libraries would help me achieve this?

Please let me know if you want more clarity on my goal

Thanks!

Comment: check `InteractiveViewer` widget - the docs say: *"A widget that enables pan and zoom interactions with its child."*

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, **software libraries or other off-site resources** are off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing.  My first thought was to use InteractiveViewer with a child SVG widget using the flutter_svg package.  The InteractiveViewer has a transformController that you can listen to so that you can calculate the position of markers after zooming and panning.  Seemed to work fine.  But if you were to zoom in too much, it would run out of memory.   How large is your floor plan?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The floorplans are not very large, one per floor in a fairly small buliding, so I don't imagine memory would be an issue. How are you displaying widgets/markers on top of the svg?